# Change screens on Android app

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the best way to switch screens on an android app, I have the main activity page with 4 buttons, the first 2 will go to websites and I want too, and other two buttons to go to other app pages I have built.

I have the new pages in the /layout/activity_two.xml

**Desired:** click "button3" on main page, then screen switches to new page

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is to create different `Activities` for the different `layouts` then use `Intent`s to go to next `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);`

but this is not normally a great idea

Answer (score 2):

The best way to switch 'screens' (which are called 'views', and refer to a rectangular area of the screen, which may or may not be the entire screen) is to use fragments (which contain views that often cover the whole screen).

When using fragments, you can have one main activity that switches between various fragments.

here is a little spiel from the android developer website:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

I found this to be very helpful, and the example is kind similar to what you are trying to accomplish (minus the web pages):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyXvq_kwfzg

Comment: Definitely use Fragments

Comment: as far as I know, fragments are the newest and easiest way to create multi-view ui in android.

Answer (score 1):

To open an external browser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("website_url_goes_here");
startActivity(intent);
```

To open another Activity (screen) of your app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: So I have to create a class and then load the xml file to the new class?

Comment: Yes, you call `setContentView()` in the second activity, just like you are doing in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can call setContentView twice or more in an activity - even if the "norm" is only to call it once.

Fragments and multiple activities are all well and good, but often it is more straightforward to call setContentView again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe usefull SlidingPaneLayout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) or DrawerLayout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) component for your purpose at the Android Support Library. Both helper for navigation into the app. So, you can switching what you want displaying content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the links in your answer; that way, if the links go stale the answer won't be completely useless.